# optional data with jsr 303

Tags: java, validation

got one here i have been pondering for a day or so.

I have a regular Java Bean and on it is a String property that can legally be null or empty, however if it is not null or empty then i have a regular expression to validate that it is a valid floating point number.

I have arranged my annotations thus

```
@Pattern(regexp = VALID_FLOAT, message = "Incorrect format")
private String elevation;
```

Problem is, when the value is null or empty it still fails validation! with "Incorrect format"

Can anyone help out here please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the `VALID_FLOAT` pattern?

Comment: By the way, the JSR 303 spec says `null` elements are considered valid...

Comment: @mthmulders the pattern is kind of irrelevant, the issue is how to stop the validation attempt if the string is empty or null. If you are after a valid float pattern i can let you have it though

Comment: If the string is `null`, it should be considered valid, says the spec. So if that is not the case, I'd say that's a bug in the implementation (don't know which one you're using). But if it's empty (i.e., `""`), the pattern is relevant, since `""` might or might not match the pattern.

Comment: @mthmulders  aha i see what you are saying now, thanks that is helpful

Answer (score 3):

[JSR-303 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) states on page 16

> While not mandatory, it is considered a good practice to split the core constraint validation from the not
>   null constraint validation (for example, an `@Email` constraint will return true on a null object, i.e. will not
>   take care of the `@NotNull` validation)

So the `@Pattern` should be valid for null values of the string. Then your `VALID_FLOAT` pattern should handle empty strings or you need to explicitly state that like `EMPTY+"|"+VALID_FLOAT`.

However I think the ambiguity for null and empty String isn't a good practice. You should decide for one.

Comment: thank you, all has become a lot clearer after your reply and mthmulders's reply.